# In the Lyris ListManager API, what values for CharSetId are allowed?

Tags: api, email, soap, content-type

In the Lyris ListManager API, when creating a mailing via `SendMailing`, one of the parameters which can be included is `CharSetID`. There is a vague reference to the `CharSetStruct`, no documentation on what specific values are allowed. There are also no other functions which address the struct (or table). What values are legal and what do they mean?

Alternatively, I would like to set the 'Content-Type' in my email header, which is why i was investigating `CharSetID`, any other suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the database structure, CharSetStruct corresponds to the ListManager mimecharsets_ table.  Common values I'm seeing are:
**CharSetID**: 1, **Name**: ISO-8859-1, **Description**: Latin alphabet No.1,- characters for western European languages
**CharSetID**: 17, **Name**: us-ascii, **Description**: (none)

These were the values in our table.  You can see what's being used in yours with this query:
    SELECT DISTINCT CharSetID_ FROM docparts_;

Comment: I am not running my own server, I am using the API so I can't run the query. Thanks.